# Gulp watch for specific file and generate other file

Tags: node.js, sass, gulp

I have this code in my gulpfile.js

```
// Sass configuration
var gulp = require('gulp');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');

gulp.task('sass', function() {
    gulp.src('*.scss')
        .pipe(sass())
        .pipe(gulp.dest(function(f) {
            return f.base;
        }))
});

gulp.task('default', ['sass'], function() {
    gulp.watch('*.scss', ['sass']);
})
```

This basically watches all scss file.

My `theme.scss` contains:

```
@import "default"
@import "buttons"
```

I want to watch for a specific file i.e `default.scss` and `buttons.scss` and if those are modified I want to `src` in my `theme.scss` and regenerate `theme.css`

How do I modify the above code to achieve this?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question, I think this might be a solution

```
gulp.task('default', function(){
    gulp.watch(['default.scss', 'buttons.scss', ..., 'the-files-you-want-to-watch'], ['sass']);
});
```

If you want to just generate theme.scss when modifying the said files, you could add something like this, and add 'sass_theme' besides 'sass' in the gulp.watch above.

```
gulp.task('sass_theme', function() {
    gulp.src('theme.scss')
        .pipe(sass())
        .pipe(gulp.dest(function(f) {
            return f.base;
        }))
});
```

Comment: Does the `sass` task make a new css file with `css` extension?